# Python method decorator to access an instance variable

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a Python class that has a couple of state variables - let's call them `self.state` and `self.process`:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(state=None, process=None):
        self.state = state
        self.process = process
```

Now, I have a LOT of methods that should yield an error if `self.state` and `self.process` are none. I don't want to have to handcode a test for each, so I was thinking, I'll do a decorator - something like this:

```
class MyClass(object):
    ...

    @needs_state
    def some_function():
        # do something
```

Now if `some_function()` is called but `self.state` is `None`, an error will be raised. Can I accomplish this with decorators - ideally just with one? (I've seen the solution that uses a class decorator and I'm not sure it does what I wish it did!). Bonus points for a good explanation for why I cannot ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Decorators are ordinary functions, and `self` is no exception to the rule. So let's say I write a decorator function that takes an argument called `self`:

```
def needs_state(fn):
    def decorator(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.state is None:
            raise ValueError('Oh no')
        return fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return decorator
```

It does not know what `self` is, because it is not in a class, but that's okay, you can use the decorator in a class, in the way you expect.

```
class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self, state=None):
        self.state = state

    @needs_state
    def some_function(self):
        print self.state
```

So, if you now instantiate the class with anything, your `some_function` will first check if `self.state` is none, because you had just decorated it. Similarly, if the class does not have a state, then the exception is raised as expected.

```
MyClass(1).some_function()  # 1
MyClass(None).some_function()  # raises
```

`self.process` is left out so you need to do some work.

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer for Python3.

Let's start with the code soup and work backwards.

```py
from functools import partial, update_wrapper
from typing import Callable, Generic, ParamSpec, TypeVar, TYPE_CHECKING

P = ParamSpec("P")
T = TypeVar("T")

class Wrapper(Generic[P, T]):
    def __init__(self, func: Callable[P, T]):
        super().__init__()
        self.func = func

        if TYPE_CHECKING:
            # Mypy and Pyright are able to infer docstrings correctly here but
            # Python can't actually run this code because methods don't have a
            # __module__, __name__ or a writable __doc__. If you're reading 
            # this answer from the future try taking away this check and see
            # if the issue got fixed.
            update_wrapper(self, func)

    def __call__(self, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> T:
        return self.func(*args, **kwargs)

    # __call__/__get__ are special, this one I just made up.
    def __call_method__(self, instance, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> T:
        return self.func.__get__(instance)(*args, **kwargs)

    def __get__(self, instance, _):
        return partial(self.__call_method__, instance)
```

And here's how you would use it.

```py
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class LoggingDecorator(Wrapper[P, T]):
  def __call__(self, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> T:
    logger.info("You decorated a function.")
    return super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)

  def __call_method__(self, instance, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> T:
    logger.info("You decorated a method.")
    logger.info(instance)
    return super().__call_method__(instance, *args, **kwargs)

logging_decorator = LoggingDecorator
```

Then when you go to use it is looks like this.

```py
@logging_decorator
def my_normal_func():
  return 42

class MyClass:
  @logging_decorator
  def my_method():
    return 42

  # Notice how `instance` is the class now!
  @logging_decorator
  @classmethod
  def my_class_method():
    return 24
```

Now let's go over how it works. Decorating a normal function works how you're probably used to but if you aren't used to making your own `Callables` the next two examples are functionally equivalent.

```
class MyDeco:
  def __init__(self, func):
    self.func = func

  def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return self.func(*args, **kwargs)

mydeco = MyDeco

def mydeco(func):
  def _mydeco(*args, **kwargs):
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  return _mydeco
```

Closures and classes are deeply related if you want to go down that rabbit hole ;)

Anyway, when we decorate a method we use the [Descriptor Protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) (i.e. `__get__`). When you have an instance object and you call `MyClass().my_method` what this does is look up `my_method` in the objects [MRO](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/) finds our decorator, sees that it has a `__get__` function and calls it passing in the instance. It's our job to return a function that takes a `self` parameter and is *bound* (meaning setting the value of `self`) to the instance. How do you bind a function to an object? With `__get__`!

So the transformations that are happening are as follows.

1. User creates an object `myobj = MyClass()`.
2. User calls `myobj.mymethod(1, 2, 3)`.
3. This calls `MyClass.mymethod.__get__(obj, _)(1, 2, 3)`
4. Our code uses `partial` to turn `__call_method__(self, instance, *args, **kwargs)` into a new function `new_method(self, *args, **kwargs)`
5. We call `new_method(1, 2, 3)`.
6. The partial resolves and calls `MyDeco.__call_method__(self, instance, 1, 2, 3)`
7. `__call_method__` logs the message, then goes and gets the undecorated `mymethod`, binds it to the instance and calls it with `1, 2, 3`.

I know this was a lot but the end result is a decorator that works on functions and methods transparently *while giving the decorator access to the instance when called on a method* (which is the big win).